# How can I translate a pango.FontDescription to something that Reportlab understands?

Tags: fonts, pdf-generation, pygtk, reportlab, pango

In a PyGTK+ based [program](https://github.com/thinkle/gourmet), I'm using Reportlab to generate PDF output. I'd like to enable users to select a font for that PDF output (partly due to [this issue](https://github.com/thinkle/gourmet/issues/729)). The canonical way within (Py)GTK+ is using a gtk.FontChooser for this sort of task, which seems to return a [pango.FontDescription](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-pangofontdescription.html).

The non-trivial part to me seems how to translate such an object to something that reportlab understands, i.e. something that I can use as an argument to `pdfmetrics.registerFont()`. Any help appreciated.

(The main issue probably being that a Pango FontDescription seems to aim at providing a uniform interface to different types of font such as TrueType, Type1, OpenType etc, while for ReportLab, one would normally use a different class to construct each of these types, such as `reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts.TTFont` etc.)

(And yeah, in the long run, I'd like to switch to cairo for PDF production. But implementing equivalents for all those nice high-level Platypus layouting functions in cairo and pango also takes a bit of doing...)